# Include File in exported JAR using packages not working

Tags: java, jar

I try to include a file into my (runnable) jar when exporting my application. 
It's a ttf-file, that is important for my pdf-generator. I put the file under `src\pdf_content\` but after exporting and running the program it tells me that the file cannot be found:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\pdf_content\bgcs.ttf (The system cannot find the path specified)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(PDTrueTypeFont.ja
       at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(PDTrueTypeFont.ja
       at com.hp.deu.vw.fis.db.schemavergleich.PDFDocumenter.createPDFDocumentati
       at com.hp.deu.vw.fis.db.schemavergleich.MainClass.createPDFandOutput(MainC
       at com.hp.deu.vw.fis.db.schemavergleich.MainClass.start(MainClass.java:242
       at com.hp.deu.vw.fis.db.schemavergleich.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:191)
```

Running the program **in Eclipse** works just fine.

I access the file using

```
// APACHE PDFBOX METHOD
bcgsFont = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, "src/pdf_content/bgcs.ttf");
```

Comment: 1) How do you access to this file? Provide code fragment. 2) Are you sure, that desired file is in `jar`? You can check it manually, jar is just archive, which can be extracted.

Comment: Didn't know that jars can be accessed that easy. Yes, file is in jar located under `pdf_content\bcgs.ttf`, therefore the access through `src\pdf_content\bcgs.ttf` cannot work. Added the way I access the file to my original question. Why does the export change the way everything is located?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass into `loadTTF` method `InputStream` instead of file path. `InputStream` could be ontained using `.class.getResourceAsStream()` method. Something, like this:

```
bcgsFont = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, PdfContent.class.getResourceAsStream("bgcs.ttf"));
```

Which class to use instead of `PdfContent` - I don't know structure of your project. For example, any class which is located in `pdf_content` package.